# Word for doing something but not wanting other people to notice?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

It's not secretly. For example, I'm at a mall with a friend, then I notice someone from my school. I point to them to show my friend, who I go to school with. But I don't want the other person to notice. So I _______ point at them. 
It's a synonym of secretly. I know it starts with an s and ends with a e sound or vowel form of y sound.

Comment: There is always "on the Q T".

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you are looking for *[surreptitiously](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surreptitious),* though *[stealthily](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stealthy), [sneakily](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sneaky),* and *[slyly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sly)* also fit the criteria.

For future inquiries of this kind, try [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/surreptitiously).

Comment: last time it took me ages to remember effortlessly
it's hard for me to translate the words into english. thank you so much x

Comment: Also covertly or discreetly.

Comment: The word you might be looking for is "subtly."